# Richfaces exception resource not found

Tags: richfaces

I am very new to Richfaces.

While using `<ui:include>` I am getting Exception as

```
Not Found in ExternalContext as a
Resource
    com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:116)
    com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.getRelativePath(DefaultFacelet.java:216)
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my application i have two files in the root of the war-file:

- *template.xhtml*
- *navigation.xhtml*

I reference *navigation.xhtml* in *template.xhtml* by *ui:include*:

```
<html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  ...
  <ui:insert name="navigation">
     <ui:include src="/navigation.xhtml"/>
  </ui:insert>
  ...
</html>
```

Maybe you forget to add the */* in the beginning of the *src* parameter